# How to use value from SQL Server in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, parameters, insert

I got value from SQL Server using this C# code:

```
SqlDataReader reader = new SqlCommand("select Top 1 Client From _ClientName group by Client order by count(*) desc", sqlCon.ShardDB).ExecuteReader();
```

How can I use this value again to insert it into another table?

Comment: Psst. This comment is unrelated to this question.  It's about the other one you had to close today because it wasn't very clear.  Which is too bad, because after your last edit, it was clearer. The answer is to use `top 1 with ties`: `select Top 1 with ties Client ...`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, for readability sake, try separating your code into separate lines, like so:

```
SQLReader reader;
SQLCommand SQLCmd = new SQLCommand();
SQLCmd.CommandText = "select Top 1 Client From _ClientName group by Client order by count(*) desc";
SQLCmd.Connection = sqlCon.SharedDB;
reader.Execute(SQLCmd);
```

If I understood your comment to Sajeetharan's previous answer, you want to know how to advance to the next result if your query returns more than one.  Have you tried `SQLReader.Read()`?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: my code working 100% but in this order i make count for name in table have a lot of names so i got only one name but i can't use this name so maybe use parameters?

Comment: Do you want to increment a count for each result returned by reader?  If so, call `reader.Read()` then increment an `int` variable.

Comment: You're welcome.  Please remember to mark the question as answered if that is all you need.

Comment: i really did before you said :D

Answer (score 1):

Just use name of the column begin returned from the database i.e  "Client" here. If it is a string, you can use `.ToString().` If it is another type, you need to convert it using `System.Convert`

```
string Value = reader["Client"].ToString();
```

Comment: i count rows in select if i use call Client will give me error so i think it's need a parameter to do this can you tell me how?